# MSSQL PHP cannot connect over apache's account

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, sql-server, httpd

I'm fighting with this for a day now, hope someone already faced with this problem and can help me out:

I have a CentOs server

```
[root@XXXXX ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

which would be a webserver with PHP enabled (already installed, php-mssql package too)

```
[root@XXXXX ~]# php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.3.3
...
Configuration
...
mssql
MSSQL Support => enabled
...
Library version => FreeTDS
```

There is an index.php with

```
$cn = mssql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die("Connection Error");
```

`$dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword` double checked.

If I call it from the browser it throws Connection Error, but if I compile it in terminal as root it works:

```
[root@XXXXX ~]# php /var/www/html/index.php
<h1> SQL CONNECTION TEST: </h1>
<h2> Result </h2>
Connection OK!Query OK!
```

I guess it's a missing permission from apache's account, but which?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running with SELinux enabled (and you should) you will need to allow apache to communicate with the database, this can be done with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

These commands will take a few seconds to run so don't worry if they don't return immediately.